# Under which conditions the integer expression $m(n-m)(n-5m)$ has 3 distinct prime factors?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I'm solving something and this is a step in the problem I'm trying to solve. We also have $n\neq m$ and $n\neq 5m$ and I'm trying to find conditions under which the expression $m(n-m)(n-5m)$ has 3 distinct prime factors, 2 distinct prime factors and only one. I tried to looking at cases:

- $m=1$ ($m$ has no prime factors)
- $m=p^k$ ($m$ has one prime factor)
- $m$ has 2 prime factors
- $m$ has 3 prime factors

Even with the first case I'm having problems. If $m=1$ then we have $(n-1)(n-5)$. If $(n-1)(n-5)$ has only one prime factor then $n-1=p^k, \: n-5=p^\ell.$ I get that it has to be $p=2, \ell =2, k=3.$ Now if $(n-1)(n-5)=p^kq^l$ I don't know that to do next.

It makes me think there should be a "smarter" way to do it, not just by brute force. Any ideas?

Comment: If $m$ and $n$ are arbitary, we will need brute force in general. If we do not have small prime factors, we will have to check $n-m$ and $n-5m$ for primality and in the worst case even factor $n-m$ and/or $n-5m$. Even the case $m=1$ will need brute force in general.

Comment: Lots of prime pairs differ by $4$, just like in the twin prime problem

Answer (score 1):

Does three prime factors mean 3 or more?
I am looking for the special cases where there are fewer than three prime factors.
If $m$ and $n$ are coprime then so are the three factors, so at least one of the factors has to be $\pm1$.
If $m$ and $n$ are not coprime, divide them both by their common factor, solve the previous case.  Then multiply $m$ and $n$ by the same $p^aq^b$.